# Relation between outer product of unit vectors and ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was reading a paper and came across some linear algebra that I do not understand. I would appreciate if someone helps me to understand the following.

Let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $i=1,\dots N$ be unit vectors. Let also $A = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ia_i^T$. That is A is sum of self outer product of this unit vectors. Suppose we know A but do not know $a_i$, the authors claim that each $a_i \in \xi(A)$, where $\xi(A)=\{a|a^TA^{-1}a \leq 1\}$ is a necessary condition. They also say that $\xi(A)$ is an ellipse. Can anyone please explain how I can understand the ellipse and the necessary condition?

Comment: Wait, unit vector as in of an orthogonal/orthonormal basis? If so, everything becomes way easier.

Comment: unit vector in euclidean space.